# Python fast execution of array of operations based on values from another array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, reference

I have setup this code using 2 python dictionaries objects with a loop, but my code needs to run faster and therefor I am looking at numpy arrays since I read that these could operate faster than dicts, especially for all numerical values.

Basically what I have is 2 arrays of data.

The first array contains variables. These variables are pulled in from a websocket service and are constantly updating. Each row represents 2 values of 1 parameter. No values will be added, all values are constantly being updated.

```
VariablesArray (this array is about 70 rows, 2 columns).
[
1.5    0.1
8      9
4      3
27     6
...
]
```

(in theory this could also be just a 1D array of 70 variables)

The second array need to be some type of fully static array containing referenced operations that need to be done and verified on these variables

```
OperationsArray (this array is about 1000 rows, 1 column)
[
VariablesArray[1,1] * VariablesArray[2,1] * VariablesArray [3,0]
VariablesArray[1,0] * VariablesArray[2,0] * VariablesArray [3,1]
VariablesArray[1,0] * VariablesArray[5,0] * VariablesArray [2,1]
...
]
```

Every time a variable changes, this list of calculations is checked, preferably only the rows that contain this updated variable, but for the sake of simplicity in this question let's perhaps recalculate everything.

If any of these multiplications returns a result higher then 100, I need to take action and trigger some alarm code.

If I put both these arrays in dictionary objects and loop through this in python, I can do 7 "OperationsArray" calculations per millisecond. Since some variables are referenced in a few hundred calculation rows, any update of those variables would take up to 100ms to calculate alarms, which is too long.

Now I am wondering what the best approach is for the fastest result. I am really new to python and coding , perhaps this is just as easy as adding these variables as specified above in these 2 arrays and then loop through the second array to see if anything is bigger than 100?

Comment: Have you looked into Numba?

Comment: We need to see some workingcode with example.  That will be easier to test and suggest improvements.

Comment: Good idea I will provide some code later today